# Creating multiple combination arrangements

Tags: r, combinations

First of all, I'm new in R. I have a dataset that consists of:

- different people (p1,p2,p3,p4)
- each person owns a particular item (A,B,C,D,E)
- each person also have an item that they wish (A,B,C,D,E) that might or might not be the same as the one that they got.

I got rid of the people that have the item that they wish. I want to create a script that can arrange the *trades* that have to occur between all the people in order for everyone to obtain what they wish. The problem is that maybe not all the people can get what they want and if a person doesn't get what he/she wishes, he/she will not trade what he/she has.

I want to create all the possible combinations.

Example

```
have    person  want    
A       P1      B    
B       P2      C    
D       P3      A    
D       P4      A    
C       P5      D
```

First Combination

```
Person Giving     P1  P2  P5  P3  

Person Receiving  P3  P1  P2  P5    

Item Exchanged     A   B   C   D
```

Second Combination

```
Person Giving     P1  P2  P5  P4  

Person Receiving  P4  P1  P2  P5    

Item Exchanged    A   B   C   D
```

Comment: What do you mean by *First* and *Second* combinations? Shouldn't just one set return all combinations?

Comment: Yes, i just listed the possible combinations for the Examples but i really meant all of the combinations

Answer (score 1):

Consider a cartesian `merge` join on itself with subset to avoid same person and match *have* and *want* between pairings.

Data

```
txt = 'have    person  want    
A       P1      B    
B       P2      C    
D       P3      A    
D       P4      A    
C       P5      D'

df <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE)
```

Merge / Subset

```
df$key <- 1
all_comb_df <- subset(merge(df, df, by="key", suffixes=c("", "_")), 
                      (person != person_) & (have == want_))[c("person","person_","have")]

rownames(all_comb_df) <- NULL
colnames(all_comb_df) <- c("PersonGiving", "PersonReceiving", "ItemExchanged")

all_comb_df

#   PersonGiving PersonReceiving ItemExchanged
# 1           P1              P3             A
# 2           P1              P4             A
# 3           P2              P1             B
# 4           P3              P5             D
# 5           P4              P5             D
# 6           P5              P2             C
```